# less time used with larger number in timeit.timeit()?

Tags: python, timeit

```
import timeit
t=timeit.timeit('x=map(lambda x:x*10,range(32))')
print(t)
```

which shows:

```
0.4678139
```

but

```
t=timeit.timeit('x=map(lambda x:x*10,range(32))',number=100)
print(t)
```

gives:

```
4.309999999999731e-05
```

I suppose number=100 should takes 100 times 0.4678139, so what's wrong here?

Comment: `timeit.timeit` runs 1000000 times by default, this is consistent with the values you are getting

Comment: as said above, if you look at the signature for timeit `timeit. timeit ( stmt='pass', setup='pass', timer=<default timer>, number=1000000, globals=None )` you see it defaults to run the test 1 million times if you dont give a number. so in your first example it takes 0.46 to run that code 1 million times. But in your second example you say run it only 100 times so of course it will be faster as it runs many many times less

Answer (score 2):

The default arguments for [`timer.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) include `number=1000000`, hence your first result is quite close to 1e4 times the second.